# Prevent edit suggestions conflicting with 'super-user' edits

Tags: discussion, support, bug, edits, suggested-edits

I submitted a suggested edit [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27312581/c-having-problems-understanding-structs) in order to remove the 'code snippet' that the OP had inserted their C++ code into.

I submitted a [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6395527), but however *another* user also edited the question while I had the edit page open, with the *exact same edit*.
As a result of this my suggested edit was submitted but however didn't change the question *at all* because the other user had already edited it:

[image]

Surely this is a bug?
Normally if a user submits an edit *while* the question is being edited a message is shown that the question has been edited, but this wasn't the case here?

Can duplicate edits in this situation be prevented?

I assume that this bug occured because the question was edited by a *super-user* and myself at the same time, thus the two conflicting with each-other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You hadn't *completed* the edit yet, so no such message could be shown.

Order of events:

- You and the OP opened the editor around the same time
- OP submitted their edit
- You submitted your edit

There was a difference between your edit and theirs; yours added some whitespace too (view the Markdown difference).

As such there was *no edit to warn the OP about*. You didn't  get a warning either, because your edit submission came too close after the OP edited. Since the OP edits were in the grace period, it is hard to determine exactly how close together your edits were submitted. On top of that, the OP deleted the question.

This is simply a limitation in how concurrent edits are handled on the site; there is no locking *while you edit*.

Comment: Yes, but if that's true, *how come my edit is shown as 'under review'*?

Comment: @cybermonkey: because your suggested edit was submitted for review. It doesn't matter here that the post is now deleted. It may be that it does mean that most reviewers won't be able to see the suggestion.

Comment: True, but if my edit was too close to the current revision, wouldn't it be rejected by the system?

Comment: @cybermonkey: no, not if the edits came in close together.

Comment: @cybermonkey: I tested with my sock account (1 rep) and I can still see the suggested edit.